# How to create hierarchical data in C#

Tags: c#, treeview

I am trying to create data to bind to Telerik's treeview control. The document suggests to create data in the following format:

```
dataSource: 
[{
    id: 1, text: "My Documents", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "rootfolder", items: [
        {
            id: 2, text: "Kendo UI Project", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                { id: 3, text: "about.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                { id: 4, text: "index.html", spriteCssClass: "html" },
                { id: 5, text: "logo.png", spriteCssClass: "image" }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 6, text: "New Web Site", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                { id: 7, text: "mockup.jpg", spriteCssClass: "image" },
                { id: 8, text: "Research.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 9, text: "Reports", expanded: true, spriteCssClass: "folder", items: [
                { id: 10, text: "February.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                { id: 11, text: "March.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" },
                { id: 12, text: "April.pdf", spriteCssClass: "pdf" }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

I have data in the format of `SortedList<string, SortedList<string, IData>>`. I would like to convert it to the above format  in C#.

Thanks

Comment: It looks as though they are telling you to convert it to a JSON format.  If you currently have it in a sorted list, how do you know what object is the child or parent of another object?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Telerik but DevExpress (personal preference which is better) and there i have to tell a TreeView which field is the NodeId and which field is the ParentId. I would suggest you add a ParentId field to your IData.

The NodeId is a unique ID with which the Tree will build up his view and ParentId is the ID which tells the Tree how to populate the layers.

Last but not least a TreeView will need a RootId as an entry point for the List.